# how do i send a random screenshot through my discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, replit

a few years ago i found this website that lets you see random screenshots people took, and i wanna make that a command in my discord bot and it works but the images dont show up in discord.

heres what i have so far

```
if message.content.startswith(prefix + "rss"):
        rss = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase+string.digits, k=6))
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Random ScreenShot:", color=0x109319)
        embed.set_image(url="https://prnt.sc/"+rss)
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: I do not know how this site works, but isn't a random string relatively unlikely to result in a valid image? You might need to verify that the image is valid somehow first. Also the link does not seem to lead to an image directly, but to the site, so you will probably need a direct link to the image.

Comment: This website works because there is only 216 combinations you can make from 6 letters and numbers. But thanks for reminding me that the url leads to a website and not an image, I'll try to see if I can get an image url.

Comment: How do you get 216 combinations? If my math is correct, (26 letters + 10 numbers)^6 yield around 2.17 billion possible combinations.

Comment: You have to multiply it by 6 not ^6

Comment: Thats not how it works, every place has 36 possible combinations, so you have to calculate 36x36x36..., as many times as there are places to fill, aka 36^n. If you do not believe me just google it, or see this thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1376044/how-many-3-character-combinations-can-be-made-using-letters-and-numbers

Answer (score 1):

prnt.sc format is (iirc) 2 letters, 4 numbers.

The image you view on the page is hardcoded in the page in b64, so the URL to image you're trying to embed is not an image. If you're wanting a URL to the image, I was able to find it in the `<head>` section in the `og:image` meta tag

[image: here's a URL in the og:image meta tag]

To get a URL to the image, make a get request to prnt.sc/xx0000, split and pop `<meta property="og:image" content="`, then split at `">` and take element `[0]`

I have probably overcomplicated this.

A simpler solution would be to paste the prnt.sc link in chat and let discord grab the meta tags and handle the embeds on its end.